# Synchronous Counter Issue

Tags: vhdl

I have a timing issue in some VHDL code for a Synchronous Counter. I cannot figure out why the Counter advance twice with 1 clock pulse.  I have tried everything including adding unnecessary code to the D-flip-flops to try and get it to work properly.  This is for a class and we must use our own models not library blocks.  I am a software programmer taking this course and struggle sometimes with the "instantaneous" assignment instead of the "serial" as in a program.

If someone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it. Thank you

```
--D-FlipFlop

ENTITY D_flipflop IS 
  PORT ( D, Clock, Reset : IN STD_LOGIC ; 
                Q : OUT STD_LOGIC) ; 
END D_flipflop ;

ARCHITECTURE Behavior OF D_flipflop IS 

Signal Q_buff : STD_LOGIC := '0';

BEGIN
  Q <= Q_buff;

  PROCESS ( Clock, Reset ) 
  BEGIN
    IF (Reset = '0') THEN
      Q_buff <= '0';
    ElSE
      IF RISING_EDGE(Clock) THEN 
        IF (D = '1') THEN  -- Was D <=Q changed as a trial fix
           Q_buff <= '1';
        ELSE
           Q_buff <= '0';
        END IF;
      END IF;               
    END IF ; 
  END PROCESS ; 
END Behavior ; 

--4 bit Synchronous counter with load
entity SyncCounter is
  Port ( CLOCK : in  STD_LOGIC;
             D : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
             Q : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
            CE : in STD_LOGIC;
          Load : in STD_LOGIC;
           CEO : out STD_LOGIC;
         Reset : in  STD_LOGIC);
end SyncCounter;



architecture Behavioral of SyncCounter is

SIGNAL ND0, ND1, ND2, ND3, CE_CLOCK : STD_LOGIC := '0';

component D_flipflop IS 
  PORT ( D, CLOCK, RESET : IN STD_LOGIC ; 
         Q : OUT STD_LOGIC) ; 
END component ;

begin

CE_CLOCK <=  (CLOCK and (CE or Load));

ND0 <= (NOT Q(0) and NOT Load) 
    or (D(0) and Load);

SC_D0: D_flipflop PORT MAP ( ND0, CE_CLOCK, Reset, Q(0));

ND1 <= (((NOT Q(0) AND Q(1)) OR (Q(0) AND NOT Q(1))) and NOT LOAD)  -- (Q(0) XOR Q(1))
 or (D(1) and Load); 

SC_D1: D_flipflop PORT MAP ( ND1, CE_CLOCK, Reset, Q(1));

ND2 <= (((Q(0) and Q(1) and NOT Q(2)) or (Q(2) and (NOT Q(0) or NOT Q(1)))) AND NOT Load)
    or (D(2) and Load);

SC_D2: D_flipflop PORT MAP ( ND2, CE_CLOCK, Reset, Q(2));

ND3 <= ((((NOT Q(0) or NOT Q(1) or NOT Q(2)) AND Q(3)) OR (Q(0) and Q(1) and Q(2) and NOT Q(3))) AND NOT Load)
    or (D(3) and Load);

SC_D3: D_flipflop PORT MAP ( ND3, CE_CLOCK, Reset, Q(3));

CEO <=  Q(0) AND Q(1) AND Q(2) AND Q(3) AND CE;  --- CEO output

end Behavioral;
```

Figure is shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely a result of logic on the clock with `CE_CLOCK <= (CLOCK and (CE or Load));`, since this may create multiple clock transitions for multiple delta time steps but at the same simulation time.

If flip-flop update has to be conditional, then make a clock enable on the flip flow, with code like:

```
process (clk, rst) is
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        if cen = '1' then  -- Clock Enable (cen)
            q <= d;
        end if;
    end if;
    if rst = '1' then
        q <= '0';
    end if;
end process;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Morten's answer isn't the whole story**

In keeping with Morten's answer - using enables, think of the D FF in the counter as having an input multiplexer with terms for HOLD (Q), TOGGLE (not Q) and LOAD (D).

An equivalent multiplexer is shown as cntdin in this example:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity cntr4 is
    port (
        d:          in  std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
        load:       in  std_logic;
        reset:      in  std_logic;
        enable:     in  std_logic;
        clk:        in  std_logic;
        q:          out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
        enab_out:   out std_logic
    );
end ;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity dff is
    port (
        d:      in  std_logic;
        clk:    in  std_logic;
        q:      out std_logic
    );
end entity;

architecture behave of dff is

begin
    process(clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            q <= d;
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;

architecture struct of cntr4 is

    component dff is
        port (
            d:      in  std_logic;
            clk:    in  std_logic;
            q:      out std_logic
        );
    end component;

    signal cntincr,cntd,cntq: std_logic_vector (q'range);

    begin

cnt_incr:         -- incrementer
    process(cntq)   
    begin
        cntincr(0) <= not cntq(0);
        cntincr(1) <= cntq(1) xor cntq(0);
        cntincr(2) <= cntq(2) xor (cntq(0) and cntq(1));
        cntincr(3) <= cntq(3) xor (cntq(0) and cntq(1) and cntq(2));
    end process;

cntdin:
    for i in cntd'range generate
        cntd(i) <= (cntq(i)    and not reset and not enable) or
                   (d(i)       and not reset and     enable and     load) or
                   (cntincr(i) and not reset and     enable and not load);
    end generate;

cntreg:
    for i in cntq'range generate
        D_FF: dff 
            port map (
                d => cntd(i),
                clk => clk,
                q => cntq(i)
            );
    end generate;

cntptr:
    q <= cntq;

en_out:
    enab_out <= enable and cntq(0) and cntq(1) and cntq(2) and cntq(3);    

end architecture;
```

In this example you get a synchronous reset almost for free (one input to each AND in the AND/OR).  It uses flip flops without either asynchronous reset or an enable.

Borrowing the test bench for cntr4 and adding not_reset to invert the reset to match SyncCounter:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity cntr4_tb is
end entity;

architecture foo of cntr4_tb is

    signal d:          std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
    signal load:       std_logic;
    signal reset:      std_logic;
    signal enable:     std_logic;
    signal clk:        std_logic := '1';
    signal q:          std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
    signal enab_out:   std_logic;
    signal reset_not:  std_logic;

begin

    reset_not <= not reset;

DUT:
    entity 
    work.SyncCounter
        port map (
                CLOCK => clk,
                D => d,
                Q => q,
                CE => enable,
                Load => load,
                Reset => reset_not,
                CEO => enab_out
        );

CLOCK:
    process
    begin
        wait for 10 ns;
        clk <= not clk;
        if Now > 720 ns then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;

STIMULUS:
    process
    begin
        wait for 10 ns;
        reset <= '1';
        load <= '0';
        d <=  X"5";
        enable <= '0';
        wait for 30 ns;
        reset <= '0';
        wait for 30 ns;
        load <= '1';
        enable <= '1';
        wait for 20 ns;
        load <= '0';
        enable <= '0';
        wait for 20 ns;
        enable <= '1';
        wait for 80 ns;
        enable <= '0';
        wait for 20 ns;
        enable <= '1';
        wait;

    end process;
end architecture;
```

And we find your SyncCounter apparently working:

[image: SyncCounter using cntr4_tb test bench]

**So why does it work?**

If you notice all the input stimulus effectively matches the clock edges with 0 delta delay differences and happens to operate on the other clock edge.

Without delta cycle coherent transitions on CE and Load you can get an extra positive clock edge caused by delta cycle skew.  There are a couple of messages here.

1. Gated clocks should be used with trepidation.
2. The output of the clock gate should be normally high, not normally low like CE_CLOCK. You'll use the low baud of CLOCK to generate the positive transition on CE_CLOCK instead of the positive transaction of either Load or CE AND'd with CLOCK.

The test bench causes CE_CLOCK to get gated during safe times, so SyncCounter works.

You can either use flip flops with enables, input multiplexers that include enable or try switching the sense of the idle state of CE_CLOCK.

It's no accident resets, enables and load enables are generally negative true.  When gating clocks it can be done with a NOT AND NOT gate (an OR gate De Morgan equivalent), saving gate delays.  Clock skew from gating the clock can be reduced to one gate delay.

The attractiveness of gated clocks comes from saving power.

You may also find using gated clocks is somewhat strongly discouraged by FPGA vendors should you want to synthesis the counter.

**Showing the clock glitch**

Because we may not have simulators that post delta cycle granularity events to a waveform dump I skewed *both* CE and Load early by 1 nsec:

[image: both CE and Load 1 ns before clock edge]

In this waveform capture you can clearly see the glitch and where the counter is 'double' incrementing.

You could also note that the rising clock edge is driven by CE and Load, Q(3 downto 0) all transition 1 ns before the clock edge.

Changing CE_CLOCK to normally high:

```
-- CE_CLOCK <=  (CLOCK and (CE or Load));

   CE_CLOCK <= CLOCK or  not (CE or Load);
```

loses the glitches, and lines up Q(3 downto 0) transitions with CLOCK edge:

[image: CE_CLOCK_STALLS HIGH]